# I want date instead of datetime from my table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which there is one column, `EnteredDateTime`. This column contains the date and time.
How do I get only the date instead of the date and time?

Comment: Look at you profile.. *"I have 3 year experience in .Net technology's and Ms Sql Server. "* I don't believe you !!!

Comment: Change the datatype to `date`?

Comment: @Popeyethesailorman: Seems your comment made his profile changed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CAST(enteredDateTime AS DATE)
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: @user3819358: You can accept the answer if it works, by clicking in the check mark next to the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Convert(Date, EnteredDateTime) as EnteredDateTime
From TableName
```

Have a look at [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  CAST(yourDateTimeColumn AS DATE) from tableName
```

for example

```
SELECT  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

gives me

```
2014-07-09
```

Refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: faster? Got any proof?

Comment: Have you read the question. OP says *"How do I get only the date instead of the date and time"* !!

Comment: This is outputting with time